# MongoDb cluster upgrade error - "Configuring analytics nodes specific auto-scaling is not yet supported."

Tags: mongodb, upgrade, mongodb-atlas

When Migrating Cluster from M5 to M10, I am receiving error as show below.
"Configuring analytics nodes specific auto-scaling is not yet supported.".

Has anyone encountered this error? If yes, how to resolve this?

Is there any way to migrate to bigger cluster plan without the "click to update" button?

[image: Error On Mongodb Atlas]

### Update 1 (20 Sept 2022)

Have posted same Q on MongoDb Forum
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/not-able-to-upgrade-from-m5-to-m10/187868

Comment: What did mongo support say?

Comment: Been 2 days.. (Sat,Sun,1/2 Mon) Waiting for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved.

Note for future visitor to this Question : This was an internal issue with Atlas. The same was fixed by support team. There was no action required from my part.